# GWT celltable enable keyboard right and left and enter for select object

Tags: java, gwt

I have a gwt celltable i need to enable right key and left key from keyboard and select the element focused with a enter key. Anyone have an example to use ? the gwt example use the mouse click for select each row element. thanks

Comment: What kind of cells do you use? For example, left and right keys are used within an input field. This makes it impossible to decide whether a user wants to move one character right or one cell right.

Comment: i need to press enter for select row and start another program

Answer (score 1):

To do so , you have to override some method of GWT . Everything is nicely explained in [this official example](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/cell/client/AbstractCell.html)

Moreover , initially you can enable keyboard control by enabling keyboard selection  policy like

```
 cellTable.setKeyboardSelectionPolicy(KeyboardSelectionPolicy.ENABLED);
```

This will enable navigation in cell table row , and selection upon space bar.

Answer (score -1):

Are you trying something varying from what GWT already provides in celltable.
Navigate to GWT CellTable demo - http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellTable

You can see use of "Enter"/"Space"/"Up"/"Down"/"Left"/"RIGHT" keys. Note and observer the behaviour per column.

They cover all use cases. The Selection Model , Key Provider and Column Type determine the response of your key strokes in the celltable.

Comment: mm i don't understand. i use public void onCellPreview(CellPreviewEvent<AbstractApplicationBean> event) {
    if (event.getNativeEvent().getKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER||"click".equals(event.getNativeEvent().getType())) {
     selected = selectionModel.getSelectedObject();       
      selectionTable(selected);   it run with muose left click but not with enter key

Comment: I am trying to say that you need not try to force a gwt cell table selection / key response behavior. Instead extend AbstractCell to implement your own "Cell" like https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCellWidgets#Cells